# Getting error when creating new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I am trying to create a new rails project I am getting this error .I have never got this error .

```
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'activesupport' (= 4.2.5) - did find: [activesupport-4.2.4,activesupport-4.2.3,activesupport-4.2.1,activesupport-4.2.0,activesupport-4.1.5,activesupport-4.1.4,activesupport-4.1.1,activesupport-4.0.13,activesupport-4.0.4,activesupport-4.0.0,activesupport-3.2.16,activesupport-3.2.13,activesupport-3.2.11,activesupport-3.2.9,activesupport-3.2.2,activesupport-3.1.3,activesupport-3.0.3] (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1311:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in `activate'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `block in gem'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `gem'
    from /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
    from /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: are you using `rvm`? If so then select a `default` ruby version. Then try

Comment: Yes I am using rvm .And default ruby version is already selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are getting this error because updated version of ruby is not being used by rvm .
Run this command

> `rvm list` 
>   Which will give you all the ruby version installed on your system and which version of ruby is being used by your computer  .Then select the latest version of ruby by this command

```
rvm use ruby version
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have gem dependencies installed

```
Could not find 'activesupport' (= 4.2.5) - did find: [activesupport-4.2.4,activesupport-4.2.3 ..... activesupport-3.0.3] (Gem::LoadError)
```

specify rails version while creating new rails app

```
rails _4.2.16_ new my_app # change the version accordingly
# You must have rails 4.2.16 installed
```